# Add file to /etc/httpd/conf.d with elastic beanstalk

Tags: httpd.conf, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I created a `.ebextensions` directory in the root of my project and added a conf file to add a file to `/etc/httpd/conf.d` but I don't see the results when I ssh to my instance.  I've made two attempts:

(1) First Attempt

Following [this AWS forum post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=236325), I created `.ebextensions/update.conf` with this content:

```
files:
  "/etc/httpd/conf.d/update.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    encoding: plain
    content: |
      TraceEnable off
```

I ran the above through a YAML linter to make sure the format is correct.

(2) Second Attempt

Following [the AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-tomcat-proxy.html), I created `.ebextensions/httpd/conf.d/update.conf` with this content:

```
TraceEnable off
```

In both cases, the file `update.conf` does not appear in the `/etc/httpd/conf.d/` directory as desired.

To make sure that my configuration was properly uploaded, I downloaded the source zip file to make sure that my .ebextensions folder was included.

Any suggestions for what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: What is the exact issue? Did you make sure your zip has ebextension, and also ssh to the ec2 machine and check if the config is there

Comment: The issue is that the `update.conf` file is not present on my instances in the `/etc/httpd/conf.d` directory.  I'm uploading my code using `eb deploy` and I afterwards downloaded the zip file to make sure the `.ebextensions` directory was properly uploaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your config file is named `.ebextensions/update.conf`. But, according to [Advanced Environment Customization with Configuration Files (.ebextensions)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html), the file extension should be `.config`:

> Configuration files are YAML- or JSON-formatted documents with a
>   .config file extension that you place in a folder named .ebextensions
>   and deploy in your application source bundle.

Try renaming your config file to `.ebextensions/update.config`.

Comment: That did it.  I got confused by the .conf extension for httpd and the .config extension for eb.  Enjoy your bounty!